# Does Azure Active Directory supports transactions?

Tags: transactions, ldap, azure-active-directory, jta, unboundid-ldap-sdk

Tried to look everywhere, but I have not found any concrete answer to this.

I have a use-case in Active Directory, where I would like to do multiple operations within a single transaction. So, if the last operation gets failed, previous operations are rolled back by the transaction manager.

I am using [UnboundId LDAP SDK](https://github.com/pingidentity/ldapsdk) and it does have a transaction support, as defined in this [link](https://docs.ldap.com/ldap-sdk/docs/javadoc/com/unboundid/ldap/sdk/extensions/StartTransactionExtendedRequest.html). But it will only work if the underlying directory server supports it.

I have come to the conclusion that Microsoft Windows Server Active Directory does not support it. But is it the same with Azure Active Directory too, because it is an enterprise directory server and identity service provider. It should have transaction support.

In the case, if Azure AD also does not provide support for transactions, what are my options here to implement those transactions manually on upper data-access layers other than directory server internally managed transactions.

Answer (score 1):

Azure AD not support Transactions.however, it is possible to 'roll your own' solution by writing an enlistment class that implements the `IEnlistmentNotification` Interface. `IEnlistmentNotification` works with both explicit and implicit transactions in the System.Transactions namespace.

Please refer the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.transactions.ienlistmentnotification?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netcore-3.1)